# Как перенаправлять вывод консоли в GUI? Текстовый квест выполнить в GUI на Python

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Имеется мой код текстового квеста, классического, с выбором вариантов и ветвления, корректно исполняется в консоли (конкретно в Thonny). Но хотелось бы, чтоб это квест выполнялся не в консоли, а в окне - насколько я понимаю, это возможно в окне GUI под Tkinter. С моими знаниями phyton я не вижу, как это сделать, хотя бы путь решения (я совсем не волшебник, я только учусь). В интернетах рылся, в частности на киберфоруме, решения не нашел. Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Что значит "Как перенаправлять вывод консоли в GUI"?

Comment: Если текстовый квест то тогда там наверное и ввод требуется?

Comment: То есть у вас есть вывод не существующей консоли типа абстрактный и как его отправить в допустим Text виджет Tk?